# Devart.Data.Oracle.Vs.OracleDataProviderPackage package did not load correctly

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, devart

I am facing this problem (*Devart.Data.Oracle.Vs.OracleDataProviderPackage package did not load correctly*) in visual studio 2015 [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MdHW.png)

the ActivityLog.xml file show this error [Log file message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihw2d.png)

```html
 <record>53</record>
    <time>2018/02/08 07:16:39.140</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Devart.Data.Oracle.Vs.OracleDataProviderPackage]Source: 
  'Devart.Data.Oracle.Vs ' Description: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l 'assembly  'Devart.Data.Design,
 Version=5.0.1555.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701 ' ou une de ses dépendances.
 Le fichier spécifié; est introuvable. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
 Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly  'Devart.Data.Design, Version=5.0.1555.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701 ' ou une de ses dépendances. 
 Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. File name: "Devart.Data.Design,
 Version=5.0.1555.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701"   at Devart.Common.Vs.d.c()   
 at Devart.Data.Oracle.Vs.OracleDataProviderPackage.c()   
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)  AVT":
 la journalisation de liaison d 'assembly est désactivée. 
 Pour activer la journalisation des échecs de liaison d 'assembly, 
 attribuez la valeur 1 à la valeur de Registre [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD). Remarque&#x00A0;:
 une certaine perte de performance est associée à l 'enregistrement dans le journal des échecs de liaison d 'assembly.
 Pour désactiver cette fonctionnalité, supprimez la valeur de Registre [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. </description>
    <guid>{7A24CFC5-F408-4574-8B07-078DFE413305}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I tried to run the command **devenv /setup** but it didn't work. I tried also to clear the cash in **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache** but it didn't work too.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of error. Provide error message as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling dotConnect for Oracle in the following way:

1. Uninstall dotConnect for Oracle (if it is currently installed)
2. Delete all Devart.* and policy.*.Devart.* files in the following folders:

   - GAC 2.0 (\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL)
   - GAC 4.0 (\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL)

You can use any file manager other than Explorer (e.g.: Total Commander) in order to navigate to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ .
If you don't have any file manager other than Explorer, then you can use Explorer with the GAC shell extension turned off. The GAC shell extension connects to Explorer using the Desktop.ini file located in the assembly folder. Rename the Desktop.ini file to display the content of the assembly folder like content of any other folder. For this, run the following three commands in Command Prompt:

1) Go to the GAC folder: 
cd %windir%\assembly

2) Remove the system and hidden attributes for the Desktop.ini file:
attrib –s –h desktop.ini

3) Rename the file to disable the shell extension
ren Desktop.ini Desktop.ini.disabled
Delete all Devart folders.

3. Clear the directories:

   - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Devart\
   - \Program Files (x86)\Devart\
   - \Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Devart\
   - \Documents and Settings\All Users\Devart\EntityDeveloper\
   - \Documents and Settings\All Users\Devart\dotConnect\
4. Install dotConnect for Oracle;

4.1. Run the installation 'As Administrator';

4.2. Make sure you have closed Visual Studio prior to performing the installation;

Is the issue solved after these actions?